# How to space these items for my table

Tags: php

i have this fully functional, i just want to space out the titles up top here, how can i do that and keep this php code functional.

```
print("<center><font size=6 color=#088A08>PK Data</font></center>");

echo
"
<hr />
<br />";




$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

echo
    "<table><tr>

        <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Victim</font></th>
        <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Level</font></th>
        <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Killer</font></th>
        <th style='text-align:center'> <font size=3 color=#088A08>Realm</font></th>
        <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Date/Time</font></th>

        </tr>";





$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT deadchar, level, class, killacct, killforumid, realm, date FROM pkdata     
ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


$deadchar = $row['deadchar'];
$level = $row['level'];
$class = $row['class'];
$killacct = $row['killacct'];
$killforumid = $row['killforumid'];
$realm = $row['realm'];
$date = $row['date'];
    echo
        "<tr>

        <td style='text-align:center'>".$deadchar."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$level."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'><b>".$killforumid."</b></td>            
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$realm."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$date."</td>           

        </tr>";

}

echo "</table>";


$conn->close();
```

Comment: So are you just looking to make the table full width and the cells evenly spaced? Using css -> table { width: 100%; } td { width: 20%; }

Comment: i really have no idea how to do thaT...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to give the same width to each column, change your echo from :

```
echo
    "<table><tr>

        <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Victim</font></th>
        <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Level</font></th>
        <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Killer</font></th>
        <th style='text-align:center'> <font size=3 color=#088A08>Realm</font></th>
        <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Date/Time</font></th>

        </tr>"
```

to :

```
echo
"<table style='width:100%'><tr>

<th style='text-align:center;width:20%'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Victim</font></th>
<th style='text-align:center;width:20%'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Level</font></th>
<th style='text-align:center;width:20%'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Killer</font></th>
<th style='text-align:center;width:20%'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Realm</font></th>
<th style='text-align:center;width:20%'><font size=3 color=#088A08>Date/Time</font></th>

</tr></table>"
```